# Java deploy webservice ejb to Windows Weblogic

Tags: java, windows, web-services, deployment

i have a problem with deploying webservice jar file to Weblogic. If i deploy on same version WL linux machine works ok. If i deploy to windows machine it gives error msg NoClassDefFound.

It cant find class i defined in webservices.xml file under handler-chain tags. its like com.something.SoapBodyHandler.

On linux, handler is working. If i deploy to windows without that tag it works.

Its like it couldn't find com/something/SoapBodyHandler

Comment: This is not related to windows/linux, but to your environment. Is your handler class part of the web service archive or did you put it in a different file? A stack trace might help.

Comment: its a part of webservice. in same package that beans are.